# How do you wii-u-gc-adapter working on 64-bit debian?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, udev, make, libraries

Following these guides (https://github.com/ToadKing/wii-u-gc-adapter/blob/master/README.md and https://dolphin-emu.org/docs/guides/how-use-official-gc-controller-adapter-wii-u/#Linux) - I've tried these steps:

```
sudo su; apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt dist-upgrade -y && apt install jstest-gtk -y
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="057e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0337", MODE="0666"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/51-gcadapter.rules
exit
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt install libusb-dev libudev-dev -y
sudo modprobe uinput
git clone https://github.com/ToadKing/wii-u-gc-adapter
cd ~/Downloads/wii-u-gc-adapter
make
sudo ./wii-u-gc-adapter
jstest-gtk
```

When I do `lsusb`, I get `Bus 001 Device 011: ID 057e:0337 Nintendo Co., Ltd`  but nothing shows up in `jstest-gtk`.

I unplugged/replugged the adapter and nothing.

I'm totally stumped. Any advice? See any obvious mistakes I'm making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is returning the off brand hardware and buying the official adapter made by Nintendo. The off brand YTEAM adapter doesn't seem to work with Linux.